# How can I run python code in remote linux server?

Tags: python, linux, bash, server

I want to run my python code (bash) in my remote server and make it running even when I turn off my Pc doesn't affect it ?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your issue, you could use `nohup`:

```
nohup python /path/to/test.py &
```

`&` is needed, so the script runs in the background.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use [tmux](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki) for that. They will create a tmux session and in that session you can run the python code (the same way that you run on bash) that is already in you remote server.

Is just a console session that you can exit and return when you want.